# Which is the best scikit-learn machine learning algorithm for different size of training data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have this data set which I need to use to train (`fit`) into my `machine learning` algorithm:

```
data= [
    {'timestamp': '1406025645732', 'datatype': 'mass', 'fat': '0.348',  'lean': '0.06'}, 

    {'timestamp': '1406025645776', 'datatype': 'body', 'value': 122.0, 'location': 'nose'}, 

    {'timestamp': '1406025645793', 'datatype': 'mass', 'fat': '0.32', 'lean': '0.04'}, 
    {'timestamp': '1406025645810', 'datatype': 'mass', 'fat': '0.308', 'lean': '0.1'}, 

    {'timestamp': '1406027645916', 'datatype': 'body', 'value': 6.0, 'location': 'eye'}, 

    {'timestamp': '1406025645949', 'datatype': 'mass', 'fat': '0.312', 'lean': '0.052'}, 
    {'timestamp': '1406025645966', 'datatype': 'mass', 'fat': '0.32', 'lean': '0.032'}, 
    {'timestamp': '1406025645983', 'datatype': 'mass', 'fat': '0.28', 'lean': '0.06'},

    {'timestamp': '1406025646000', 'datatype': 'gender', 'value': '0.3096', 'size': '7.0'}
]
```

I have a sample of data which contains 3 data types:

- `body`
- `mass`
- `gender`

The number of samples per data types **is random** (*i.e.*, sometimes I can have 10 samples of `mass`, and 1 of `gender`. Or I could have 300 samples of `mass`, and 20 of `body`).

Either way, I would like to have a trainning set with this kind of non-consistent data.

**Is this possible?**

**What should be the best scikit-learn training algorithm for this?**

- Logistic Regression?
- Naive Bayes?
- k-Nearest Neighbor?
- Classification and Regression Trees?
- Support Vector Machines?

Here is some sample code, but I don't know the next path to achieve this.

Please advice me which step should I follow, or maybe some tutorial where I can learn and paste here the solution for this.

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import pandas
import numpy
import pylab

# this is one traning set for Abel
features = [
    {'timestamp': '1406025645732', 'datatype': 'mass', 'fat': '0.348',  'lean': '0.06'}, 

    {'timestamp': '1406025645776', 'datatype': 'body', 'value': 122.0, 'location': 'nose'}, 

    {'timestamp': '1406025645793', 'datatype': 'mass', 'fat': '0.32', 'lean': '0.04'}, 
    {'timestamp': '1406025645810', 'datatype': 'mass', 'fat': '0.308', 'lean': '0.1'}, 

    {'timestamp': '1406027645916', 'datatype': 'body', 'value': 6.0, 'location': 'eye'}, 

    {'timestamp': '1406025645949', 'datatype': 'mass', 'fat': '0.312', 'lean': '0.052'}, 
    {'timestamp': '1406025645966', 'datatype': 'mass', 'fat': '0.32', 'lean': '0.032'}, 
    {'timestamp': '1406025645983', 'datatype': 'mass', 'fat': '0.28', 'lean': '0.06'},

    {'timestamp': '1406025646000', 'datatype': 'gender', 'value': '0.3096', 'size': '7.0'}
]

# 0 for Abel, 1 for Jasminne
labels = [0]

# Here I train the model with the above arrays
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels) # crashes here due to the use of a dict, instead of an array
joblib.dump(clf, 'model.pkl')
```

Many thanks.

Comment: what is your goal? are you trying to predict the datatype from the features? or given a dataype, are you trying to predict a variable (e.g. given that `dataype="mass"`, predict `fat`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logistic regression is applied when your dataset can be fit as a linear graph.Since your dataset contains multiple features,you can go ahead with KNN,Decision trees,Naive Bayes. KNN is simple but is computationally exhaustive.
Decision Trees[CART] is a better choice as the algorithm will understand the data unlike KNN. If you are familiar with the concepts of SVM, you can try it,but it requires in depth understanding.

Comment: are you saying its not possible to use Logistic Regression because there are multiple features? why would he need in-depth understanding of SVM in order to use a library such as `scikit-learn`?

Comment: Applying regression doesn't depend on number of features.

Comment: There is no point in applying SVM using Scikit-learn when you don't know how the algorithm works.

Comment: indeed it does not, so what point are you making with logistic regression? because its a linear model? and i disagree, it is _exactly_ the point of machine learning libraries like `scikit-learn` to be able to apply _any_ algorithm to a given problem _without_ requiring a detailed in-depth understanding of the algorithm. Its enough to know when and why a certain algorithm is useful and when and why not.

Comment: According to me, real understanding of an algorithm is when you know how it works irrespective of using the library